# Xcode - upload image from Iphone Simulator to local folder using PHP

Tags: php, xcode, upload, nsurlconnection

I'm following this person's [tutorial](http://www.geronimobile.com/sending-image-from-xcode-to-server/) on how to upload an image from Xcode to a local folder on my computer.

When I compile and run the code, everything is fine and I get no errors, but the image is not in the folder where it's supposed to be.

**A brief summary of how the program should work:**

1. User chooses an image from their photo library using UIImagePicker
2. The UIImageview gets updated with the UIImage that the user has chosen
3. User presses the "upload" button which calls the IBAction "uploadImage"
4. The uploadImage function will convert the UIImage to a NSData and send that to PHP
5. PHP will upload the image to the select folder

The code for the IBAction "uploadImage"

```
-(IBAction)uploadImage{

//this is the url where the PHP file is located
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/~andy/uploadimage.php";

//Convert selected UIImage to NSData
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage,.3);

if (imageData != nil)
{
    NSString *filenames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageUploaded"];      

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filenames\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[filenames dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //I use a method called randomStringWithLength: to create a unique name for the file, so when all the aapps are sending files to the server, none of them will have the same name:
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",[self randomStringWithLength:10]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    //Run code async 
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSData *returnData = data;
         NSLog(@"data recieved!%@", returnData);

         //Do what you want with your return data.   
     }];
}
}
```

This is the php code for uploadimage.php:

```
<?php

$target_path = "/";  //where I want the uploaded images to go
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name'] );

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {

    echo "Image uploaded";
} 
else {

    echo "Upload Failed";
}
?>
```

The directory where I want the image to be stored in is the same local directory where uploadimagep.php is located in localhost/~andy/

**Results after running the program**

Everything returns successful but there's no image in my folder in localhost/~andy/

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I feel like I made a rookie mistake somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#define DataDownloaderRunMode @"myapp.run_mode" 
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                               timeoutInterval:60]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
// We need to add a header field named Content-Type with a value that tells that it's a form and also add a boundary.
// I just picked a boundary by using one from a previous trace, you can just copy/paste from the traces.
NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundarycC4YiaUFwM44F6rT";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
// end of what we've added to the header
// the body of the post
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
// Now we need to append the different data 'segments'. We first start by adding the boundary.
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Now append the image
// Note that the name of the form field is exactly the same as in the trace ('attachment[file]' in my case)!
// You can choose whatever filename you want.
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[file]\";
filename=\"picture.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// We now need to tell the receiver what content type we have
// In my case it's a png image. If you have a jpg, set it to 'image/jpg'
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// Now we append the actual image data
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
// and again the delimiting boundary    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// adding the body we've created to the request
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                       delegate:self 
                                                       startImmediately:NO]; 
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:DataDownloaderRunMode]; 
[connection start];
```